# Cancel a PayPal subscription when a user upgrades

Tags: php, paypal, upgrade, subscriptions

We provide PayPal recurring subscription for a site on yearly basis and user will able to upgrade the subscription level in between if he want, now my problem is that if once user will register for platinum level of subscription from gold level so I need to cancel the previous subscription of the user, Is it possible to cancel a particular subscription  from my site in background after a new subscription register for the user is done?

I know about `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API but does not find any documentation for api to integrate it, or any example for it, what is profile ID gives from the paypal? i am using ipn and it gives me `subscr_id` not `profile_id`

Please share your information,

Thanks in advance,
Vhora.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I do not know which platform are you using. If you are using ASP.NET C# then the following like will help you

http://programming-language.weebly.com/1/post/2013/12/cancel-recurring-payment.html